# MVC3 putting a newline in ViewBag text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, text, line-breaks, viewbag

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  I am looping through a DataTable.  Some rows are importing OK, some are not.  I am wanting to send a list of errors back to the view in a list format.  I am assigning the following text to a ViewBag property

```
Input error on Row(1) Cell(3) Input string was not in a correct format.<br/> Input error on Row(4) Cell(3) Input string was not in a correct format.<br/>
```

I was hoping the br would write a line break in the HTML.  It does not.  I want the error message to look like this

```
Input error on Row(1) Cell(3) Input string was not in a correct format.
Input error on Row(4) Cell(3) Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `string[]` to hold your errors.  That way they are a well-formed and distinct set of errors instead of just one long string.

In your Controller, initializing the `ViewBag` property:

```
ViewBag.Errors = new string[] { "First error", "Second error" };
```

In your View, displaying these errors:

```
@foreach (string error in ViewBag.Errors)
{
    @Html.Label(error)
    <br />
}
```

### Separation Of Concerns

*You shouldn't be handling markup layout within your Controller* (i.e. line breaks, or any other DOM elements).  *The presentation should be handled solely by the View*.  Which is why it would be best to pass a `string[]`.

Comment: @Shark....I chose this answer based on the "separation of concerns" you mentioned

Comment: @MikeTWebb Absolutely, I'm a firm believe that us MVC Developers should strictly adhere to this.  It allows for easily maintainable code.

Answer (score 15):

When you throw into your view, use

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Test)
```

instead of

```
@ViewBag.Test
```

That will signify to the compiler that string is html and does not need to be encoded as such.

Comment: @post....this worked but, again, decided to keep the markup language in the View and not the controller.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

Controller:

```
 ViewBag.Msg += Environment.NewLine + "xxxx";
```

View:

```
<p class="@ViewBag.MsgColor">
        @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Msg.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))
 </p>
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of doing this is to simply add a `<br />` to the line time in the controller code as ViewData["msg"] which can then be pulled from the razor page as below.

Controller Code:

```
ViewData["msg"] = "Your Query <br /> has been processed.";
```

Razor Form Code:

```
@Html.Raw(@MsgFormatted)
```